# Batch for loop through variables, can't cd to each?

Tags: variables, loops, batch-file

I have a for loop in a batch file:

```
@echo off
set logpath1=C:\path\to\first\log
set logpath2=C:\path\to\second\log
FOR %%G IN (%logpath1% %logpath2%) DO (
  pushd %%G
  pushd ..\
  for %%D IN (%CD%) DO SET "dirname=%%~nxD"
  popd
  echo Will prefix files in %%G with %supername%
  :: do operations.
  popd
)
```

However, this doesn't seem to change my working directory. If I run the script from

```
C:\tmp\path\to
```

then I get

```
Will prefix files in C:\path\to\first\log with tmp
Will prefix files in C:\path\to\second\log with tmp
```

My purpose is to zip up log files in multiple directories. I've tried chdir, cd /d, and &~pd0 instead of %CD%, and searched high and low. Can anyone tell my why this doesn't work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your batch file and use `!CD!` instead of `%CD%` in the loop. Depending on where `%supername%` is set you may need to use `!` there too.

Comment: Aha! I looked up some documentation on delayed expansion but I guess I didn't quit grasp the concept. Thanks Joe!